# Unable to open a saved Gephi project file

Tags: error-handling, graph-theory, gephi

Recently I worked on a project done in the network visualization and analysis software Gephi, and I saved it with the ".gephi" extension. However, when I try to reopen the file, it gives the following error message:-

"The project file couldn't be opened. Please check the file has .gephi extension.

```
              XMLStreamException - ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
              Message: Premature end of file."
```

I'm a beginner in Gephi and only an amateur programmer. I do not understand this error message, and thus have no ideas on how to resolve it. I tried updating Gephi to the latest version. I also tried to open the file from within Gephi. Neither of those steps have resolved the problem. Can anyone help me out with this, please?

Answer (score 1):

The error message "premature end of file" means that the xml file was not complete. I suppose that the whole file is empty or just the xml part of the file. so maybe the file got corrupted while saving.

Can you try to open the file with notepad or a hexeditor to verify that it has some content?

Answer (score 1):

There must be some bug on the gephi files writing or reading process.
In order to identify the problem it would help if you can post a gephi log file when each error happens.

You can find the log file on gephi user directory (check http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Troubleshooting)
For example in Windows 7 the path is C:\Users\Your_User\AppData\Roaming.gephi\dev\var\log\messages.log

Also, if you can share the files, it will be easier to fix.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to [an open bug](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/812) where Java6 is used to save the gephi file and then Java7 is used to load the file, say on a different machine.

The jdk used by Gephi can be specified in /etc/gephi.conf or alternatively it can be specified as a parameter --jdkhome when launching Gephi.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with java and javac:

If you created your gephi file with open java-6-openjdk (for example) and then you sitch your java to java-7-openjdk, then this problem surges.

I fix my gephi returning to the same java and javac executables in Linux by:

(In terminal)
sudo update-alternatives --config java

and then

(In terminal)
sudo update-alternatives --config javac

Hope this can help!